Neo4j Startup Failure Windows 10
I am trying to run Neo4j on a Windows 10 mobile workstation. I keep getting a repeated failure to start up. I have upgraded the JavaSDK from the original version 11 to 17, and then to 21 by placing the binaries from Oracle on the system path. I have set a NEO4J_HOME environment variable to the folder containing the Neo4J bin, certificates, conf folders etc. I have try launching Neo4j from an elevated command prompt as administrator. Despite these efforts the startup failure persists.
Here is the terminal output from the command, neo4j console --verbose:
Executing command line: powershell.exe -OutputFormat Text -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command Get-Service neo4j | Format-Table -AutoSize
Directories in use:
home:         C:\Users\user\Downloads\neo4j-community-5.20.0-windows\neo4j-community-5.20.0
config:       C:\Users\user\Downloads\neo4j-community-5.20.0-windows\neo4j-community-5.20.0\conf
logs:         C:\Users\user\Downloads\neo4j-community-5.20.0-windows\neo4j-community-5.20.0\logs
plugins:      C:\Users\user\Downloads\neo4j-community-5.20.0-windows\neo4j-community-5.20.0\plugins
import:       C:\Users\user\Downloads\neo4j-community-5.20.0-windows\neo4j-community-5.20.0\import
data:         C:\Users\user\Downloads\neo4j-community-5.20.0-windows\neo4j-community-5.20.0\data
certificates: C:\Users\user\Downloads\neo4j-community-5.20.0-windows\neo4j-community-5.20.0\certificates
licenses:     C:\Users\user\Downloads\neo4j-community-5.20.0-windows\neo4j-community-5.20.0\licenses
run:          C:\Users\user\Downloads\neo4j-community-5.20.0-windows\neo4j-community-5.20.0\run
Starting Neo4j.
Executing command line: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-21.0.2\bin\java.exe -cp C:\Users\user\Downloads\neo4j-community-5.20.0-windows\neo4j-community-5.20.0\plugins\*;C:\Users\user\Downloads\neo4j-community-5.20.0-windows\neo4j-community-5.20.0\conf\*;C:\Users\user\Downloads\neo4j-community-5.20.0-windows\neo4j-community-5.20.0\lib\* -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djdk.nio.maxCachedBufferSize=1024 -Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=stackdepth=256 -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+DebugNonSafepoints --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint --home-dir=C:\Users\user\Downloads\neo4j-community-5.20.0-windows\neo4j-community-5.20.0 --config-dir=C:\Users\user\Downloads\neo4j-community-5.20.0-windows\neo4j-community-5.20.0\conf --console-mode
2024-06-02 13:30:39.960+0000 INFO  Logging config in use: File 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\neo4j-community-5.20.0-windows\neo4j-community-5.20.0\conf\user-logs.xml'
2024-06-02 13:30:39.979+0000 INFO  Starting...
2024-06-02 13:30:41.099+0000 INFO  This instance is ServerId{3ced4df6} (3ced4df6-f0dc-42c7-8826-6de9713d2030)
2024-06-02 13:30:42.206+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 5.20.0 ========
2024-06-02 13:30:42.312+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j on localhost:7474.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting Neo4j database server at C:\Users\user\Downloads\neo4j-community-5.20.0-windows\neo4j-community-5.20.0\data\databases
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:278) ~[neo4j-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.build(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:213) ~[neo4j-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.createNeo(CommunityBootstrapper.java:38) ~[neo4j-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:184) [neo4j-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:99) [neo4j-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:30) [neo4j-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.GlobalExtensions@a50ae65' failed to initialize. Please see the attached cause exception "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair".
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:334) ~[neo4j-common-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:56) ~[neo4j-common-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:85) ~[neo4j-common-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:269) ~[neo4j-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.extension.FailedToBuildExtensionException: Failed to build kernel extension Extension:UserDataCollectorExtensionFactory[UDC] because it is compiled with a reference to a class, method, or field, that is not in the class path: 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/AnnotationIntrospectorPair'. The most common cause of this problem, is that Neo4j has been upgraded without also upgrading all installed extensions, such as APOC. Make sure that all of your extensions are build against your specific version of Neo4j.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.ExtensionFailureStrategies.wrap(ExtensionFailureStrategies.java:56) ~[neo4j-kernel-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.ExtensionFailureStrategies$1.handle(ExtensionFailureStrategies.java:68) ~[neo4j-kernel-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.AbstractExtensions.init(AbstractExtensions.java:68) ~[neo4j-kernel-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:317) ~[neo4j-common-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:56) ~[neo4j-common-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:85) ~[neo4j-common-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:269) ~[neo4j-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/AnnotationIntrospectorPair
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<clinit>(ObjectMapper.java:402) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
        at org.neo4j.udc.UserDataCollector.<clinit>(UserDataCollector.java:71) ~[neo4j-udc-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.udc.UserDataCollectorExtensionFactory.newInstance(UserDataCollectorExtensionFactory.java:42) ~[neo4j-udc-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.udc.UserDataCollectorExtensionFactory.newInstance(UserDataCollectorExtensionFactory.java:33) ~[neo4j-udc-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.AbstractExtensions.newInstance(AbstractExtensions.java:124) ~[neo4j-kernel-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.AbstractExtensions.init(AbstractExtensions.java:62) ~[neo4j-kernel-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:317) ~[neo4j-common-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:56) ~[neo4j-common-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:85) ~[neo4j-common-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:269) ~[neo4j-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair
        at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526) ~[?:?]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<clinit>(ObjectMapper.java:402) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
        at org.neo4j.udc.UserDataCollector.<clinit>(UserDataCollector.java:71) ~[neo4j-udc-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.udc.UserDataCollectorExtensionFactory.newInstance(UserDataCollectorExtensionFactory.java:42) ~[neo4j-udc-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.udc.UserDataCollectorExtensionFactory.newInstance(UserDataCollectorExtensionFactory.java:33) ~[neo4j-udc-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.AbstractExtensions.newInstance(AbstractExtensions.java:124) ~[neo4j-kernel-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.AbstractExtensions.init(AbstractExtensions.java:62) ~[neo4j-kernel-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:317) ~[neo4j-common-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:56) ~[neo4j-common-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:85) ~[neo4j-common-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:269) ~[neo4j-5.20.0.jar:5.20.0]
        ... 5 more
2024-06-02 13:30:42.323+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
2024-06-02 13:30:42.323+0000 INFO  Stopped.
org.neo4j.server.startup.BootProcessFailureException: Neo4j web server failed to start. See log for more info.
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.ProcessManager.waitUntilSuccessful(ProcessManager.java:76)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.BootloaderOsAbstraction$ConsoleProcess.postStart(BootloaderOsAbstraction.java:97)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.ProcessManager.run(ProcessManager.java:52)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.WindowsBootloaderOs.console(WindowsBootloaderOs.java:101)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.Bootloader$Dbms.console(Bootloader.java:470)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.ConsoleCommand.execute(ConsoleCommand.java:41)
        at org.neo4j.cli.AbstractCommand.call(AbstractCommand.java:92)
        at org.neo4j.cli.AbstractCommand.call(AbstractCommand.java:37)
        at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:2041)
        at picocli.CommandLine.access$1500(CommandLine.java:148)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2461)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2453)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2415)
        at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2273)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2417)
        at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2170)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.Neo4jAdminCommand.call(Neo4jAdminCommand.java:123)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.Neo4jAdminCommand.call(Neo4jAdminCommand.java:42)
        at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:2041)
        at picocli.CommandLine.access$1500(CommandLine.java:148)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2461)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2453)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2415)
        at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2273)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2417)
        at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2170)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.Neo4jCommand.main(Neo4jCommand.java:41)

The ouput of java --version is:
openjdk 21.0.2 2024-01-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.2+13-58)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.2+13-58, mixed mode, sharing)


Looks like you need the Jackson classes in your classpath

More precisely, you're missing jackson-databind

As far as I can tell the jars that I presume contain those classes are in NEO4J_HOME\lib folder. These are the jars listed as being there, data-bind is among them:
jackson-annotations-2.17.0.jar
jackson-core-2.17.0.jar
jackson-databind-2.17.0.jar
jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.16.0.jar
jackson-jaxrs-base-2.17.0.jar
jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.17.0.jar
jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.17.0.jar
I could add the lib folder to the path, although I think Neo4j should be able to find it's own components with just the NEO4J_HOME variable set to the folder that contains the lib folder.

Executing command line:... (from the error output) How exactly are you executing that?

I open up  either a command prompt window or a power shell window, navigate to NEO4J_HOME folder then execute a "bin\neo4j console --verbose" command line.

Right. Try THIS instead

Well, I had been using the latest version of Neo4j Community edition which is 5.20.0. So, just for giggles I downloaded the previous version 5.19.0 and it seems to be working as expected. I suppose the problem was just what the terminal output suggested, a build issue.

Wow gOOse, what is all that a jar fix?

It's a (potential) fix for what I suspect could be a faulty start up routine you've got
